# Typescript Namespace reference not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, namespaces, typescript-typings

I am trying to experiment with typescript namespaces. It works perfectly when i dont import other modules but when I import other modules in my case `sort` the exported function `get` cant be used in other file even though they are in same namespace.

```js
import { sort } from "../sort"

namespace Api {
    export async function get(url:string){
        const res = await fetch("api/"+url)
        return await res.json()
    }
    export class Users {
        private uid: string
        constructor(uid: string){
            this.uid = uid
        }
        public async getUserProfile(){
            return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/profile`)
        }
        public async getUserSongs(){
            return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/musics`)
        }
    }
}
```

```js
/// <reference path="api.ts" />

namespace Api {
    export class Track{
        private track_id: string
        constructor(track_id){
            this.track_id = track_id
        }
        public async hasLiked(){
            return await get("/track/"+this.track_id+"/hasLiked")
        }
    }
}
```

It says `could not find name get`

But when i dont import `sort` it works perfectly

```js
namespace Api {
    export async function get(url:string){
        const res = await fetch("api/"+url)
        return await res.json()
    }
    export class Users {
        private uid: string
        constructor(uid: string){
            this.uid = uid
        }
        public async getUserProfile(){
            return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/profile`)
        }
        public async getUserSongs(){
            return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/musics`)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add import statement to the file it turns that `.ts` file into a module, and "moves" all declarations in the file into the scope of that module.

So `namespace Api` is not seen outside of its module definition and removes it from global namespace. There are a few ways to deal with it:

1. You can turn you main `Api` file into definition file by changing its extension to `d.ts` and wrap `namespace Api` into `declare global {}`. By that you don't even need triple slash import, it will still be available in global scope. Your new `api.d.ts` should look like this:

```js
import { sort } from "./sort";

declare global {
  namespace Api {
    export async function get(url: string) {
      const res = await fetch("api/" + url);
      return await res.json();
    }
    export class Users {
      private uid: string;
      constructor(uid: string) {
        this.uid = uid;
      }
      public async getUserProfile() {
        return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/profile`);
      }
      public async getUserSongs() {
        return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/musics`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Ommiting top-level import and using dynamic import like this:

```js
namespace Api {
  export async function get(url: string) {
    const sort = await import("./sort");
    const res = await fetch("api/" + url);
    return await res.json();
  }
  export class Users {
    private uid: string;
    constructor(uid: string) {
      this.uid = uid;
    }
    public async getUserProfile() {
      return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/profile`);
    }
    public async getUserSongs() {
      return await get(`/u/${this.uid}/musics`);
    }
  }
}
```

3. Simply turning `namespace Api` with `Track` into `d.ts` resolves the issue

Working with declaration merging and modules in typescript is pretty complex and i think there are still many workarounds and pitfalls about it so my answer can definitely be extended.

Comment: Ive been looking for the solution for this problem for a while and i couldn’t get anything. This answer will help me alot thanks.